# AWS CloudWatch Log stream not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some AWS EC2 instances logging to CloudWatch Log Groups. When I open a Log Group, I can see my log streams listed:

[image]

However, when I click on one of the streams, I get an error:

> Log stream not found The log stream version_0.2.41 date_2018-06-25
>   instance_i-02962ec6fbfd20c4c could not be found. Check if it was
>   correctly created and retry.

[image]

All this used to work before (it broke down somewhere in the last two weeks) and nothing has been modified on our part.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: try restarting your servers

Comment: @Aditya already did that, to no avail...

Comment: Not sure how you create the instances, stacks etc. but it seems that something went wrong much before the instance/application would try to log to CloudWatch.